# How to delete rows from excel file, where cell value matches a criteria

Tags: excel, vb.net

In my database there are 2 different text values in column "E":
1. "client1" and 2. "client2".
So I export everything to Excel to do some calculations with both of them and after that I want to split the file to 2 separate workbooks. In one will be the data with the Value "client1" and in the other "client2".

What I have done is copy everything from one sheet to another workbook, so I have 2 workbooks and I want to delete the rows with the value "client2" in column "E" and in the second workbook I'm planning to delete all rows with the value "client1", after that comes the saving part

```
            Dim oBookkd1 As Excel.Workbook
            oBookkd1 = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
            oSheet.Copy(After:=oBookkd1.Sheets(oBookkd1.Sheets.Count))
            oBookkd1.Sheets(1).delete()

            Dim osheetkd1 As Excel.Worksheet = oBookkd1.Worksheets(1)
            Dim numrowskd1 As Integer = oBookkd1.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count()
            For currentRow = 2 To numrowskd1 Step 1
                If osheetkd1.Cells(currentRow, 5).Value = KDname1Origin Then
                    osheetkd1.Cells(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next

            Dim pathobook2 As String = "C:\TEST\TestingFile.xlsx"
            oBookkd1.SaveAs(pathobook2, 51) ' 51 == xlsx
            oBookkd1.Close()
            oBookkd1 = Nothing
```

I do not have any error message, but nothing gets deleted. Every row with "client1" and "client2" are in both files saved. How can I delete the specific rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using .cells(,) requires a row and column to be functional, otherwise it just does nothing and shows no error.

Try using .rows() to delete instead.

```
If osheetkd1.Cells(currentRow, 5).value = KDname1Origin Then
   osheetkd1.Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete
   currentRow -= 1
End If
```

Note that when you delete a row, the following row will shift up to replace it. Your row counter will continue and skip the row that got shifted up unless you -1 the currentRow to repeat it.

Comment: Great explanation, makes definitely sense and is working. Thank you